# How to Isolate S3 bucket access to different SSO roles based on team tag applied on s3 buckets

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

We follow the Tag-based approach to isolate access to the users of different teams. However, we are facing difficulties in applying this approach on S3 buckets i.e. users are still able to access the S3 buckets meant for other team members even when we use aws:ResourceTag condition key in the IAM policy attached to their respective SAML SSO role.

While the isolation seems to be working with other services like EC2 and secrets manager but it is not working with S3 buckets.